# XMLHttpRequest.status is "0" for AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, status

I am trying to create an app in Javascript that fetches data from a barcode database API (http://upcdatabase.org/api). When I make the AJAX requests, the GET requests are getting through to the API. I can see from the API's website how many requests I've made.

However, I am getting an XMLHttpRequest.status of "0" every time, on Firefox, Chrome, and Edge. I have a feeling I'm missing something since this is my first time doing this.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
var upc = prompt("Enter UPC Code:");

var requestUrl = "https://api.upcdatabase.org/product/" + upc + 
    "/73114EC2F9C47240583DBF3AA190CB4C";

function httpGetAsync(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true);  
    xmlHttp.send();
    alert(xmlHttp.status);       
}

httpGetAsync(requestUrl);
```

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: The status is 0 because the call has not returned, yet...

Comment: Would you mind elaborating? Am I asking for the status too early in the code?

Comment: @Odocoileus AJAX is asynchronous. You're asking for the status before anything has happened. Put it into the `onreadystatechange` function.

Comment: @Barmar I tried that, but got the same result, unfortunately. (I'm going to revisit the AJAX tutorials regardless, I don't think I understand this)

Comment: Until `readyState == 4`, I don't think `status` gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status):

> Before the request is complete, the value of `status` will be 0.

The request isn't complete until `readyState == 4`, so it's normal to see `0` if you log `status` before that test is successful. Try this:

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            alert(xmlHttp.status);
            if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
        }
    };
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true);  
    xmlHttp.send();
}
```